# XML message not transformed using orchestration once application is deployed

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

The xml messages coming out of my send port do not reflect my orchestration used to transform the message.

Although I tested the message map and observed the expected transformation of XML, I am confused on how to test the orchestration that uses the map.

**The orchestration has the following:**

- ReceiveMessage
- ConstructMessage => Transform
- SendMessage

After I deployed the Biztalk application and provided source messages to the instance, I observed that the messages coming off the send port still do not reflect the expected transformation. Instead, these messages have the same format as the source XML schema.

NOTE:

I am learning Biztalk.

I have stopped and restarted the server instance within the Administration Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PassThruReceive then I suspect that you have some other filter set for your Send Port and that your Orchestration is not even instantiating. Try using the XmlReceive pipeline. This will run the XmlDissasembler mentioned above which will read the namespace and root node and publish the message to the message box.

I suspect that you are subscribing in your Orch by message type, in which case, will pick up the message. When this happens, if you get 2 messages output, then you do indeed have another filter on your send port.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the first time you have tried this, it's probably because the Message isn't making trough the Orchestration because the Ports aren't Bound properly.  Make sure the Deployed Orchestration is Bound to the right Receive Port and Send Port (and Host) and Enabled.

Comment: And also check that your Orchestration is sending out the transformed message and not the original one that the Orchestration receives. P.S.  If all you are doing in the Orchestration is a Transform then you will want to not use an Orchestration at all and instead do the transform in the send port and use filter rule on the send port.

Comment: I have verified my send and receive port bindings. I have verified the map being used. The orchestration is enabled on the Admin Console. I also deleted the contents of the orchestration and set the map for my send port. Yet, I still am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Verify if you are using the XmlDissasembler Pipeline on your Receive Location.

Comment: I'm using the default: PassThruReceive. Is that okay?

Comment: If you're using PassThruReceive then I suspect that you have some other filter set for your Send Port and that your Orchestration is not even instantiating. Try using the XmlReceive pipeline. This will run the XmlDissasembler mentioned above which will read the namespace and root node and publish the message to the message box. I suspect that you are subscribing in your Orch by message type, in which case, will pick up the message. When this happens, if you get 2 messages output, then you do indeed have another filter on your send port.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I do not believe I have subscribers. I'm using a "File" transport type for my "Receive Location". I simply drop an xml file into a directory and look for the transformation result in the specified output directory.

Comment: @SuitedAces : Your suggestion worked regarding XmlReceive pipeline. Please relay your solution as the answer and I will give you credit for it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Although it does seem weird to me that you were still getting a message in your output directory!